# How to close threads in Java?

Tags: java, io

Write 100 positive and 100 negative random integers alternately to the numbers file, listing them separated by a space. Then read this file and scatter the read numbers into 2 files: positive_numbers and negative_numbers, with positive and negative numbers, respectively.

Three files are created. The numbers file contains both positive and negative numbers. In the numers_positive file, only positive ones are present (as they should be). And the file numers_negative is empty. I think it's about closing threads, but I can't figure out how to close them correctly.

```
public class IO {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    FileWriter fw1 = null;
    File file = new File("D:/numbers.txt");
    FileWriter fwnp;
    FileWriter fwnn;

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            fw.write(" " + getRandomNumber(1, 100));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fw != null)
                    fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/numbers.txt");
        fwnp = new FileWriter("D:/numbers_positive.txt");
        int c = fr.read();
        while (c > 0) {
            fwnp.write(c);
            c = fr.read();
            fwnp.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        try {
            fw1 = new FileWriter(file, true);
            fw1.write(" " + getRandomNumber(-100, -1));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fw1 != null)
                    fw1.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:/numbers.txt");
        fwnn = new FileWriter("D:/numbers_negative.txt");
        int c = fr.read();
        while (c < 0) {
            fwnn.write(c);
            c = fr.read();
            fwnn.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static int getRandomNumber(int a, int b) {
    if (b < a)
        return getRandomNumber(b, a);
    return a + (int) ((1 + b - a) * Math.random());
}
```

}

Comment: `Threads` are not used in this question. You simply forgot the last `finally` block where you close `fwnn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted:

- You are not using threads, so this it not about threads.
- You don't "close" threads.  Threads are not closable.
- You *do* need to close input/output streams ... and you are not doing that in *all* of places you need to in your program.

But the modern way to close a stream doesn't involve `finally`.  Way back in Java 7, they introduced the [*try with resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax which will automatically close resources for you.  For example:

```
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        fw.write(" " + getRandomNumber(1, 100));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fw != null)
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

can be written as

```
    try (fw = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
        fw.write(" " + getRandomNumber(1, 100));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Note that `fw` will be auto-closed.  It is better to make `fw` a local declaration so that it is out of scope after the statement:

```
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
        fw.write(" " + getRandomNumber(1, 100));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // fw is out of scope.
```

Also, you don't need to call `flush` after each write when you are writing to a file.  Any buffered output is written when the output stream / writer is closed.  You just need to make sure that the stream / writer *is always closed*.